# Contract Not Deploying In Truffle Tests

Tags: truffle, testing, ganache, truffle-test

I am trying to do a simple test on Truffle, but it seems that the deployed() promise is never being executed.

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require('MyContract')

contract('MyContract', function(accounts) {

    it('My Test', function () {
        MyContract.deployed().then(function (instance) {
            console.log('Deployed');
            assert.equal(1, 2, "This should fail");
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            })
    })
})
```

When I do `truffle.cmd test --network ganache` the test just executes and doesn't log anything to the console.  It seems that no code in the deployed() promise is being executed.  If I do `console.log(MyContract)` I can see the contract, so it seems that it is being found by the Truffle test.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have `MyContract.deploy(<CONSTRUCTOR PARAMS>)` somewhere in your migration scripts? `MyContract.deployed()` will return the instance deployed in the migration scripts.

Comment: Yes i have that, and it is working correctly when i use the contract from in my app (not from the test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the promise:

```
...
it('My Test', function () {
    return MyContract.deployed()...
});
...
```

Alternatively, you can use async functions:

```
...
it('My Test', async function () {
    var myContract = await MyContract.deployed();
    console.log(myContract.address);
    ...
})
...
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that first return! I was looking for a more complicated solution :)

Comment: It's very easy to miss something in JS. ;-)